# CKEDITOR functions + settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, ckeditor

I've declared the editor this way:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'content',{
    toolbar:'Basic'
});
```

1. The editor doesn't change to the `basic` style.
2. I want to use a function such as `editor.resize(x,y)` but I get the error that `Uncaught ReferenceError: editor is not defined` How do I refer to the textarea that I've just created to be an editor?

Answer (score 0):

1. Because you haven't defined `config.toolbar_Basic`.
2. Becasue the `editor` variable is not global. You can get the instance of editor for example from `CKEDITOR.instances` object, or from events:

   ```
   CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( evt ) {
       console.log( evt.editor );
   } );
   ```

Comment: 1. Where do I define that? So if I store th variable like this: var editor = evt.editor I can then refer to the variable editor?